# virtio filesystem mounted as readonly -- why?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, virtio

On the guest I mounted a directory of the host as follows:

```
# mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio /sharepoint /share
```

Indeed, the filesystem seems to be read/write:

```
# mount
...
/sharepoint on /share type 9p (rw,relatime,sync,dirsync,access=client,trans=virtio)
                               ^^
```

`/sharepoint` is configured as follows:

```
Type: mount
Driver: Path
Mode: Mapped
Write Policy: Immediate
Source Path: /path/to/source/on/host
Target Path: /sharepoint
```

The permissions on the source path is `777`.

And yet, when I try to do write into `/share` in the guest, I get the following error:

```
root@guest:/share# touch .hello
touch: cannot touch '.hello': Read-only file system
```

Does not matter if I'm root or a normal user on the guest, the result is the same.

I already tried restarting the VM, after changing the permissions on the host path, did not change the situation.

**Question:** Any idea what could be wrong? Or what I should check?

Comment: Just a guess... It might have something to do with `access=client` and some ACL on the host... maybe try `-o access=any` or `=user` (this is supposed to be the default). More info: https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/9psetup#Mounting_the_shared_path